# Please kindly advice on kubectl --label-columns and -L label1 -L label2

Tags: kubectl, minikube

Using minikube, deployed simple app according to "Kubernetes in action", chapter "3.3.2 Specifying labels when creating a pod"

minikube version v1.32.0

kubectl version v1.28.3

[kubectl get pod -L label1,label2 and -L label1 -L label2 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHErh.png)

Expected -L label1,label2, --label-columns label1,label2 and -L label1 -L label2 output to be the same, however using "kubectl get pod" or "kubectl get service" with -L or --label-columns doesn't output actual labels when provided with comma separated list.

Is this a known behaviour or local setup/version issue? Any best practice recommended to avoid this one?